# Random search term showing up in the searchbox

Tags: mysql, catalogsearch, search-terms

I've noticed recently that on one of our stores, random search terms start showing up in the searchbox. They're specific terms, previously searched by customers. The problem is however, it happens at random, and I haven't been able to reproduce the issue ever since, but it does happen to our customer. 
For example:
[image]

Does anyone happen to know where this is coming from?

Comment: Are you using any custom search module? Sounds more like auto-fill by the browser

Comment: No we're not using any custom search modules at the moment. That's what I thought as well until one of our team members had the same issue with a search term he had never used or seen in his entire life

Comment: You would need the source of a page where it happens. If it's a Magento module it should be at least in the source. Also search trough the database for the string. perhaps it's stored in some search terms table